# Warning: Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have the following code:

```
var dummyData = {
    "activities": [
        { "date": "19/06/2015 19:00", "user": "Dan", "display": "First Item" },
        { "date": "19/06/2015 19:00", "user": "Andrew", "display": "Second Item" },
        { "date": "19/06/2015 19:00", "user": "Trevor", "display": "Third Item" },
        { "date": "19/06/2015 19:00", "user": "Bob", "display": "Fourth Item" }
    ]
};

$("#sysActTable").dataTable({
    "data": dummyData.activities,       
});
```

I have tried several variations but I am always getting the error that points to [this page](http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4). My HTML is as follows:

```
<table id="sysActTable" class="table table-hover" style="margin-bottom:0px">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width:20%">Date</th>
                                <th style="width:30%">User</th>
                                <th style="width:50%">Display</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width:20%"></td>
                                <td style="width:30%"></td>
                                <td style="width:50%"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
```

again I have tried a number of varieties. Why am I getting this error below?

> DataTables warning: table id=sysActTable - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: middle section describes the error in the link (between the code). parameter and row index are both 0

Comment: I think  "data": dummyData.activities,   goes without the last comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your [data](http://datatables.net/reference/option/data) is an array of objects. By default, DataTables expects data to be an array of arrays.

You need to use [columns.data](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) option to describe your data structure.

```
$("#sysActTable").dataTable({
    "data": dummyData.activities,
    "columns": [
       { "data": "date" },
       { "data": "user" },
       { "data": "display" }
    ]
});
```